# Is it possible to have csv.DictReader format certain columns as something other than string?

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

`csv.DictReader()` by default pulls values in columns as strings.  ***Is there a way to specify the conversion for certain columns?***

I end up doing a lot of this minor annoyance every time I access the list of dictionaries created by `csv.DictReader()` that has non-string elements in it:

```
with open("data.csv","r") as data_file:
    items = csv.DictReader(data_file, fieldnames=('id', 'length', 'note'))
    for item in items:
        item['length'] = float(item['length'])  #### <--- MINOR ANNOYANCE 
        # ... do loop stuff
```

It would be easier if I could tell `csv.DictReader` that when it gets to a certain field, it should do a `float()` (or `int()`, `date()` etc.) conversion.

Comment: Not out of the box, no. And how'd you specify such conversions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `csv.DictReader(data_file, fieldnames=('id', 'length', 'note'), fieldconv={'id': int, 'length': float})` where `fieldconv` isn't specified, or, the field can't be converted, use the default `str()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box, no. You can either subclass `DictReader()` or create a generator function that maps your rows for you:

```
def convert_fields(iterable, **conversions):
    for item in iterable:
        for key in item.viewkeys() & conversions:
            item[key] = conversions[key](item[key])
        yield item
```

For Python 3, substitute `dict.viewkeys()` for `dict.keys()`, as Python 3 returns dictionary views by default.

Wrap your `csv.DictReader()` with that, adding conversion functions for each of your columns:

```
with open("data.csv","r") as data_file:
    items = csv.DictReader(data_file, fieldnames=('id', 'length', 'note'))
    items = convert_fields(items, length=float)
    for item in items:
        # item['length'] is now always a float
```

for column names that don't map to a python identifier (with spaces, etc.) pass in a dictionary with `**{..}` syntax:

```
with open("data.csv","r") as data_file:
    items = csv.DictReader(data_file, fieldnames=('id', 'length', 'note'))
    fieldconv = {'id': int, 'length': float, 'spaced column': float}
    items = convert_fields(items, **fieldconv)
    for item in items:
        # item['length'] and item['spaced column'] are now floats
        # item['id'] is always an int
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `'spaced column'` idea? I don't quite follow it's purpose.

Comment: @Jamie: the function lets you specify convertors as keyword arguments, but literal keyword arguments to a function must be valid Python identifiers. That is, unless you use a dictionary and apply it as a set of keyword arguments using the `**mapping` syntax. So normally `convert_fields(items, spaced columname=float)` is invalid Python, but `convert_fields(items, **{'spaced columnname': float})` is not.

Comment: @Jamie: the alternative is to always have to specify one argument, a dictionary, for the conversion mapping; but since you can already specify short fieldnames for `DictReader()`, the more compact use of keyword arguments makes for nice, clean, Pythonic syntax here.

Comment: This seems like it would be a nice extension to `DictReader`.  Considering what's in python already, I'm surprised to not see it there already.

Comment: Yes, I do prefer the pythonic method of using the keywords.  Very elegant, and nearly exactly what I was hoping for in my comment in the original question above.

Comment: Not all CSV data is so easily converted and heterogenous. The luxury of ignoring corner cases is not available to the Python library, and it was easy enough to add this. That's what iterators are good at, plugging stuff together like this.